# How set responsive of background images in css

Tags: css

I have problem in reponsive background images in css, My css code is :-

```
/*** Map ***/

ul#continents {
    list-style: none;
    background: url(images/map.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 580px;
    height: 268px;  
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul#continents li {
    position: absolute;
}

ul#continents li a{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And the HTML :-

```
<ul id="continents">
    <li id="northamerica">
        <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_America">
            <span>
                <strong>North America</strong> 
                Population: 528,720,588
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

....

How can i set the images  "map.png" as responsive.

Note: I use map tool to get hover of any country

Comment: you can use background:position to show specific part of full background

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `background-size:` with `contain` or `cover`.
`contain` : will keep your background image proportional inside the `ul` tag, but may not cover all the space.
`cover` : will keep your background image proportional too, but insted of fit inside the tag, it will fill the tag, preventing blank areas. Still, the image may not be fully visible.